# Probability of a type II error

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

To test the hypothesis that the nonconforming proportion p of a process is .20, a sample of 100 pieces was drawn at random.
A) Letting alpha = 0.05, set up a critical region for the number of observed defectives to test this hypothesis against a two-sided alternative
B) If the process now shifts to a 0.10 fraction nonconforming, find the probability of a type II error for the alternative in part a.
C) Without repeating the work, would you expect the probability of a type II error to be the same if the process shifted to 0.30? Explain

How do I answer b? I'm drawing a complete blank here so please have a descriptive answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: You are getting votes to close because you have not shown your work so far and asked for specific help where needed. Please 'take a tour' of our site to learn how it works and to learn how to ask good questions. // I am not exactly giving you answers because (I suppose) you are to work this using normal approximations. But I think it is important for you to understand that with modern software one can easily get exact answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is intended that you use a normal approximation to the null binomial distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n=100,p=.2).$

For a test with significance level $\alpha=0.5,$ you need to
reject when the number $X$ of nonconforming pieces in $n = 100$ is $X$ is lower than $E(X) = 20$ and $X$ is higher than 20 in just
the right way. Specifically, you want critical values $L$ and $U$
so that $P(X \le L) + P(X \ge U) \le 0.05,$ but coming as close to
the target significance level $\alpha = 0.5$ as possible.

Using R [where `qbinom` is a binomial quantile function (inverse CDF)], we explore how to cut about probability $0.025$ from
each tail of $\mathsf{Binom}(100,0.2):

```
qbinom(c(.025,.975), 100, .2)
[1] 12 28
```

This suggests using $L \approx 12, U\approx 28.$ Let's see if these values work, by summing the tail probabilities. [In R, `dbinom` is a binomial PDF.] A little
experimentation suggests using critical values $L = 12, U = 29.$

```
sum(dbinom(c(0:12, 28:100), 100, .2))
[1] 0.05948038                        # over 5%
sum(dbinom(c(0:12, 29:100), 100, .2))
[1] 0.04534896                        # just under 5%
```

So we are actually testing at the level $\alpha = 4.53\%.$ Because of the discreteness of the binomial distribution it is not possible to choose lower and upper critical values for a test at *exactly* the 5% level.
(A) The *critical region* is $R=\{X \le 12\}\cup\{X \ge 29\}.$

For (B), for the probability of Type II Error, you want $$P(\mathrm{Fail\; to\; rej\;} H_0| p = 0.1) = P(R^c | p = 0.1)\\
= P(13 \le X \le 28\,|\, p = 0.1) = 9.1982.$$

```
sum(dbinom(13:28, 100, .1))
[1] 9.1981788
```

For (C): The probability of Type II error for $p = 0.3$ is $0.3768.$

```
sum(dbinom(13:28, 100, .3))
[1] 0.3767595
```

If you use normal approximations, then it may *seem* as if you can bet
a test at exactly the 5% level, but that is because the normal distribution is continuous. Even so answers from normal approximation should not be much different.

The figure below show the null (blue), part B alternative (maroon) and part C alternative (dark green)
binomial distributions. The critical region consists of integers *outside*
the vertical dotted lines.)

[image]

```
x = 0:50;  pdf.0 = dbinom(x, 100, .2)
hdr="Null (blue) and Alternative Distn's"
plot(x, pdf.0, type="h", lwd=3, col="blue", ylim=c(0,.13), main=hdr)
pdf.b = dbinom(x, 100, .1)
 lines(x-.12, pdf.b, type="h", lwd=2, col="maroon")
pdf.c = dbinom(x, 100, .3)
 lines(x+.12, pdf.c, type="h", lwd=2, col="darkgreen")
  abline(h=0, col = "green2")
  abline(v=c(12.5, 28.5), lwd=3, col="orange", lty="dotted")
```

Comment: I would rather learn how to do it manually. So far, I found the critical region is Z>= 1.96

Then I calculated p using test on a single proportion p formula 

Z= (Y/n-p0)/square root of [p0(1-p0)]

and found that -0.584<p<0.984 for p=0.20, then I tried to recalculate z with the p = 0.10. Then I got -22.8<z<29.47 so...Yeah I'm pretty sure I got something wrong.

Comment: @BruceET : it's always a pleasure to read your answers! (+1)

Comment: Good to see you've got a start toward your goal. Please edit your work towards the critical region into your question (not comments). It may help to imagine normal curves approximating the distributions in my figure. The SD of the null dist'n is $\sqrt{np_0(1−p_0)}.$ Show some progress and you might get help with parts where you're stuck. I've revised my figure to show all three distributions; I hope all three distributions are clear.

Comment: The best-fitting normal dist'n to the null binomial distn is $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 20, \sigma=4)$ so the lower and upper critical values will be roughly $20 \pm 1.96(4).$ More precisely R code: `qnorm(c(.025,.975), 20, 4)` returns values
$12.16014, 27.83986.$

Comment: @BruceET : in your answer (row 22 of the answer) you wrongly typed 9.1982 instead of 0.1982

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it.